# Scraping child pages and concatenating the results in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following spider for Scrapy. I need to scrape not only the top level pages in my sitemap but also the pages that are 1st-level children of those pages. Then I need to concatenate the results of the children's scrape with the body item from my parent parse method. Could anyone help me with the code to do something like this?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from cvorgs.items import CvorgSite

class CvorgSpider(SitemapSpider):
  name = 'cvorg_spider'
  sitemap_urls = ["http://www.urbanministry.org/cvorg_urls.xml"]

  def parse(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
   item = CvorgSite()
   item['url'] = response.url
   item['title'] = hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()
   item['meta'] = hxs.select('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
   body = ' '.join(hxs.select('//body//p//text()').extract())
   item['body'] = body.replace('"', '\'');
   return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you need to scrape a data like a url and re scrape it again .
here you need to use **yield** function .
like i fetch a suburl and redirect to give a new url. Here in example 
**callback=self.parse_category_tilte** defines the function where the output from the
**(complete_url(link)** function will go:

```
sites1 = hxs.select('//div[@class="left-column"]/div[@class="resultContainer"]/span/h2/a/@href')
        items=[]
        for sit in sites2:
            link=sit.extract()
            yield Request(complete_url(link), callback=self.parse_category_tilte)
```

now the complete_url returns a new url:

```
def complete_url(string):
    """Return complete url"""
    return "http://www.timeoutdelhi.net" + string
```

now re scrape in the parse_category_tilte function:

```
sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="box-header"]/h3/text()')       
        items=[]   
        for site in sites:
            item=OnthegoItem()
            item['ename']=site.extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Hope this helps and upvote.:)

Comment: I see where you have the initial scraping in your first code block. But it looks like your third code block (parse_category_tilte) creates a new Item for the results of the scrape. How would I instead get the results of the scrape to append to a field in the original parent Item?

If you can help explain that, then I will upvote your answer. Right now, I'm not sure if it is applicable to my use case.